# Need specific formatted out in PostgreSQL using json_build_array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I need a specific output format for set of data. Details are as follows :

**Table Structure**

create table sample_table
( id integer,
name character varying,
);

**Sample Data**

[image: sample_data]

**Output Needed :**

```
"chartData" : [
 [1, "xx" ],
 [2, "yy" ],
 [3, "zz" ]
          ]
```

"chartData" is the key of json_build_object. I need the output as a single JSON Object.
Somehow, it is doable using combination of json_build_object and json_build_array. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_agg()`:

```
select jsonb_build_object(
    'chartData',
    jsonb_agg(jsonb_build_array(id, name))
) js
from mytable
```